# Problemas con .htaccess en Apache2 Debian

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Tengo instalado en mi server local (xampp+wordpress) una página con wordpress donde tengo un archivo `.htaccess`, este archivo se encuentra en: `xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\Directorio\.htaccess` junto con todos mis archivos `.php`, aquì me funciona correctamente todo.

Ahora mi problema es que mi servidor nacional esta montado en Debian Apache2.x. En el tengo el wordpress instalado corriendo perfectamente en esta direccion `/var/www/hosproma/`.

Dentro de esa carpeta pase mi carpeta Directorio con todo y me funciona todo excepto la config que tengo en el `.htaccess`.

Busqué en internet como configurar el apache, le configuré el módulo, cambie el archivo dentro de sities-viables. No sé realmente que le falta. Voy a poner mi achivo `.htaccess` a ver si esta mal.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^modificar/(\w+)$ modificar.php?id=$1
```

No sé si deba cambiarle algo por haber cambiado de carpeta o de sistema.

Comment: te fijaste si esta activo el mod rewrite en apache?

Comment: Si mano ya lo solucione, era ponerle esto Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews al archivo saludos

Comment: @OmarSarmientoRolo quizás deberías publicarlo como respuesta a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Asegúrate que tienes el mod_rewrite activado
2. En el Virtual Host de tu web debes tener la directiva AllowOverride All:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *>
       #Todo lo que tengas +
      <Directory /var/www/hosproma/>
          AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Reinicia el servicio de apache2